What is the relevance of the phrase ' ..And he began to say...' in Lk 4:21?
Apropos the BHE question at  When Jesus read from the Scroll of Isaiah, did he translate it into Aramaic?.
We see in Lk 4:20-22 ( NKJV) how Jesus proceeds after reading from Isiah :

Then He closed the book, and gave it back to the attendant and sat down. And the eyes of all who were in the synagogue were fixed on Him. 21 And He began to say to them, “Today this Scripture is fulfilled in your hearing.” 22 So all bore witness to Him, and marveled at the gracious words which proceeded out of His mouth. And they said, “Is this not Joseph’s son?”

Of immense importance is Jesus' action of sitting down immediately after  the reading. He was permitting the faithful to soak themselves in the scripture.
The phrase " He began to say...." , is equally important. But, the Evangelist does not narrate what Jesus spoke on that day other than citing him mentioning the fulfilment of Isiah's prophecy . But, was that enough to elicit 'marvel' from the faithful ? Didn't Jesus speak much more than what is recorded in Lk 4 ?
My question therefore is: What is the relevance of the phrase ' ..And he began to say...' in Lk 4:21 ?

The custom in the 1st centaury synagogue meeting was simple:

Someone was appointed to lead the service.  In this case it was Jesus
That leader would begin by standing at the lectern to read a selected passage of scripture -- Jesus selected the passage from Isaiah 61 in this instance.
The leader would then sit on the preachers' chair to begin a sermon.

In this instance, Jesus is recorded as starting his sermon with the opening sentence: (Luke 4:21)

and He began by saying, “Today this Scripture is fulfilled in your
hearing.”

Thus, Luke does nothing more than record the scripture reading and Jesus opening statement of His sermon.  I am not sure how else he could have recorded what occurred.

Thanks, Dottard. Did you mean " nothing more" in the concluding paragraph ?

@KadalikattJosephSibichan - yes - now corrected.  Thanks for pointing this out.

We need to be careful not to read too much into the details of a story like this.
Standing and sitting
This is likely to be a simple cultural expression. For example, standing for the scripture reading has been a ritual in Jewish services down through the centuries. Those who do so point to stories such as the people standing as Moses met God and received the commandments, or as Ezra read the Law after the return from exile:

Exodus 19:17
Then Moses led the people out of the camp to meet with God, and they stood at the foot of the mountain.
Nehemiah 8:4-5 (NIV)
Ezra the teacher of the Law stood on a high wooden platform built for the occasion... Ezra opened the book. All the people could see him because he was standing above them; and as he opened it, the people all stood up.

Likewise, Jesus most likely sat because that was what Jewish rabbis did when teaching. In which case, Jesus is not doing anything special here. See for instance the opening sentences of the Sermon on the Mount:

Matthew 5:1-2 (NIV)
Now when Jesus saw the crowds, he went up on a mountainside and sat down. His disciples came to him, 2 and he began to teach them.

Note that this is what we should expect. Christians believe that Jesus' identity and message were unique; but they also believe it was delivered in a particular historical and cultural place. So we should expect to see examples of normal Jewish customs as we read through the gospels.
He began to speak
This sentence should be understood as a summary sentence, and a focus on what was important in Jesus' message. This is the full story:

Luke 4:16-30 (NIV)
16 He went to Nazareth, where he had been brought up, and on the Sabbath day he went into the synagogue, as was his custom. He stood up to read, 17 and the scroll of the prophet Isaiah was handed to him. Unrolling it, he found the place where it is written:
18 “The Spirit of the Lord is on me,
because he has anointed me
to proclaim good news to the poor...
20 Then he rolled up the scroll, gave it back to the attendant and sat down. The eyes of everyone in the synagogue were fastened on him. 21 He began by saying to them, “Today this scripture is fulfilled in your hearing.”
22 All spoke well of him and were amazed at the gracious words that came from his lips. “Isn’t this Joseph’s son?” they asked.
23 Jesus said to them, “Surely you will quote this proverb to me: ‘Physician, heal yourself!’ And you will tell me, ‘Do here in your hometown what we have heard that you did in Capernaum.’”
24 “Truly I tell you,” he continued, “no prophet is accepted in his hometown. 25 I assure you that there were many widows in Israel in Elijah’s time, when the sky was shut for three and a half years and there was a severe famine throughout the land. 26 Yet Elijah was not sent to any of them, but to a widow in Zarephath in the region of Sidon. 27 And there were many in Israel with leprosy[g] in the time of Elisha the prophet, yet not one of them was cleansed—only Naaman the Syrian.”
28 All the people in the synagogue were furious when they heard this. 29 They got up, drove him out of the town, and took him to the brow of the hill on which the town was built, in order to throw him off the cliff. 30 But he walked right through the crowd and went on his way.

What is worth noting about this wider setting is that in fact we do have other words that Jesus said on this occasion. But they follow the initial response from the audience. Jesus' opening sentence is his claim to be the Messiah: "Today these words of scripture have been fulfilled." His further words focus on their response to that claim, which turns out to be one of rejection.
So Luke has written a story that sums up those two aspects of Jesus' message: The arrival of the kingdom, and the call to repentance. And he reinforces that twofold reality by the response of his hearers: Initially they affirm the quality of his teaching, but soon they turn on him. For those who knew Jesus as he grew up, the contrast between the young carpenter and the Messianic claim was a bridge too far.
Note also that Jesus refers to "what we have heard that you did in Capernaum." So it would be wrong to understand the opening sentence as applying only to what Jesus says on this occasion. They are not responding to a single sentence; they are responding to the totality of Jesus' growing reputation up to this point. And again, we know about this from the four-gospel set, but we don't have all the details in Luke. For Luke is a good story teller. He knows which bits to include, and which to leave out. We need to apply the same level of common sense as readers.

+1 Many good points here but I have to disagree that "today these words have been fulfilled" constitutes a claim to be the messiah. The prophet Isaiah was the first to declare "The Spirit of the Sovereign Lord is on me, because the Lord has anointed me to proclaim good news to the poor." (Isaiah 61:1) Jesus does claim here to be a prophet, but in Luke's gospel he has not yet claimed to be the messiah.

@DanFefferman, you're right to warn us against reading a later understanding of Jesus' identity into an earlier passage. But at the minimum, Jesus is claiming in some way to be a fulfilment of the Isaiah prophecy. And my understanding of the Isaiah passage is that it had messianic connotations in Jesus' time. Also, Jesus deliberately chose this text. I think it's at least plausible to make a messianic connection even at this stage of his public ministry.

Peter Kirkpatrick, Lk 4:17 says that the scroll of Isiah WAS GIVEN TO HIM. Jesus did not deliberately choose the text.

Once again, context. Yes, it says that the Isaiah scroll was handed to Jesus. But in the very next sentence it also says that "he unrolled it and found the place where it is written...". We don't have the right to emphasise one sentence and completely ignore the other. When I read the whole passage, it seems natural to conclude that Jesus made some sort of intentional choice. He selected a passage that related to his own mission and identity.
